# SQL queries within a loop

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, google-code

Google code suggests that you should AVOID sql queries within a loop. The reason being that the multiple round trips to the database significantly slows your scripts down. The example query they give is this.

```
$userData = array();
foreach ($userList as $user) {
     $userData[] = '("'.$user['first_name'].'", "'.$user['last_name'].'")';
}
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES'.implode(',',$userData);
mysql_query($query);
```

My questions are...
1. How important is it to keep your query out of a loop, and is it always avoidable?
2. How can you implement a SELECT statement with this same logic.

i.e. Let's say I have this query.

```
$index=0;
while ($index < count($id)) {
     $result[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblInfo WHERE site_id = '".$id[$index]."' ");
     $index++;
}
```

How can this SELECT statement be executed outside of a loop? I have a large amount of SELECT statements that are far more complex than this. So if deemed necessary, I'd like to get these queries out of loops. If someone out there is concurring with google, could you please post some sample code.

Any response will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first example makes no sense. I doubt your "scripts" have to do bulk inserts constantly. While for just one-time operation such a loop doesn't that matter. As for selects - just learn SQL

Comment: SQL is SET based, rather than procedural.

Answer (score 8):

You can use MySQL `IN` operator with a list of IDs.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,4,6,8,5,6)
```

It can handle even very lengthy lists of thousands of IDs (certainly better than thousand `SELECT`s). But in such case you also should consider design of your application. If you need to use IN with thousands of IDs on every page load, something is very wrong in you design.

`INSERT`s can also be condensed into one query, see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Generally, most queries in loops can be usually [rewritten as subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html). however in such case, you have to choose between performance and readability/maintainability. Subqueries generally are hell to understand and optimize/debug.

Answer (score 1):

How important avoiding the round trip cost is to you depends on a few things.

First, how many round trips are you making?  If you're making 3 or 4, you can probably ignore the advice if heeding it would be painful.

Second, how costly is the round trip for you in your setup?  If a roundtrip to the db takes 100 ms, that's to be avoided much more seriously than if it only takes 2 ms.

Third, how time-sensitive is the process that needs to do the queries?  If you're making a user wait, you should really pay attention to this - users hate to wait!  If you're using an Ajax process that runs behind-the-scenes and does some work, maybe it's less important (though you'll still have to watch out for timeouts, maybe).

Basically, Google's advice is good, in that wasted time is wasted time.  However, depending on your specific case, wasted time may be more or less serious to you, your system, and your users.

Comment: Right now, I make 17 trips to the database. This number will double as we are opening more locations over the next couple years. As for the time it takes, that I'm unsure of. I will perform some tests to see how long it is taking. I'm not using AJAX (yet), but it is certainly a possibility in the future. The wasted time is not THAT important, but I would like to do things the "RIGHT" way, as I strive to learn efficient programming.

Comment: But how frequently, how long does each one take, and how much does a delay matter to you?  Those are really the important questions.  Still, as your number grows, the likelihood is that Google's suggestion will be more and more beneficial to you.